# Trig Substitution Integral Question

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

My class is going over trig substitution, but I can't figure this one out, mostly because it's not in the correct form. Could someone help explain how to set up this problem?

$$ \int \frac {1}{x^2-25} dx $$

Comment: You want the $25$ to be a $1$, so factor $25$ from the denominator to start.

Comment: Let $x=5\tan t$, and use the fact that $\tan't=1+\tan^2t$.

Comment: Sorry, it's x^2-25, not x^2+25.

Comment: But shouldn't I have to put the denominator under a radical to get the proper form in order to do a substitution?

Comment: "But shouldn't I...?" - nope!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need trig here: use partial fractions.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using trigonometric substitution, the correct one would be $x=5\sec\theta$.
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{x^2-25} &= \int\frac{\color{red}{5}\sec\theta\color{red}{\tan\theta}\,d\theta}{\color{red}{25\tan^2\theta}} = \frac{1}{5}\int\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan\theta}\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{5}\int \csc\theta\,d\theta \\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\ln\left|\csc\theta + \cot\theta\right| + C \\
\end{align*}
Drawing a right triangle with base angle $\theta$, hypotenuse $x$ and adjacent side $5$ (so that $\sec\theta = \frac{x}{5})$, we see that the opposite side must have length $\sqrt{x^2-25}$, so $\csc\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}$ and $\cot\theta = \frac{5}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{5}\ln\left|\csc\theta + \cot\theta\right| + C
&= -\frac{1}{5}\ln\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-25}} + \frac{5}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}\right| + C \\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\ln\left|\frac{x+5}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}\right| + C \\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left|{x+5}\right|-\ln\left|{\sqrt{x^2-25}}\right|\right) + C \\
\\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left|x+5\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{x-5}\sqrt{x+5}\right|\right) + C \\
\\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left|x+5\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{x-5}\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{x+5}\right|\right) + C \\
\\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left|x+5\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|{x-5}\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|{x+5}\right|\right) + C \\
\\
&= -\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|x+5\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|{x-5}\right|\right) + C \\
\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\left(\ln|x-5| - \ln|x+5|\right) +C
\end{align*}

This is definitely not the most straightforward solution but it's nice to know there's so inconsistency with the choice.

Comment: Or $x = 5 \csc \theta$

Comment: @GFauxPas: yes, but I usually only use sin, tan, or sec.

Answer (score -1):

The integral
$$ \int \frac {1}{x^2-25} dx $$
isn't in the correct form yet, but you can manipulate it easily
$$ \int \frac {1}{x^2-25} dx =  \int \frac {1}{25((\frac{x}{5})^2-1)} dx = \frac{1}{25}\int \frac {1}{(\frac{x}{5})^2-1} dx$$
now, just substitute $u=\frac{x}{5}, du=\frac{dx}{5}$
$$ \frac{1}{5}\int \frac {1}{u^2-1} du$$
continuing to manipulate...
$$ \frac{1}{5}\int \frac {1}{u^2-1} du = \frac{1}{5}\int \frac {1}{\sec^2(\sec^{-1}u)-1} du=\frac{1}{5}\int \frac {1}{\tan^2(\sec^{-1}u)} du$$
From here on, it's just an inverse trigonometric substitution (albeit a messy one because it involves $\mid u \mid$). It would be far better to use inverse hyperbolic trigonometric substitution in this case, or as Robert Israel has already pointed out, partial fractions.

Comment: -1 There is no need for these manipulations.

Comment: A good reason to use manipulations like these is to show that the expression already is in the correct form. Another reason is to show that what the inexperienced student may believe to be a trigonometric substitution is actually an inverse trigonometric substitution. I believe that looking at concepts from multiple angles facilitates deeper understanding for the student.